# Using a macbook pro keyboard for developing software. Typing square brackets and curly braces

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

Recently, I replaced my Windows laptop with a MacBook Pro. I'm very happy that I've made the choice to switch to OS X. It's indeed very user friendly. I've noticed that when you press a key on your keyboard longer than normal that you can choose different variants (with accents and things like that). As a student in electronics engineering I need te curly braces {} and sqaure brackets[] often. Can I change the way that the ( and ) keys work and add the square brackets and curly braces to it so they appear as an option when pressing the () keys?

**Edit:** (I know I can type them by using option and option and shift key, but I find the little popup menu very nice feature)...
**Edit 2:** If this is possible, I definitely want to add the ohm sign, and other symbols that I use on a regular base...

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Navigate to `/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/PlugIns/PAH_Extension.appex/Contents/Resources/`.
> 2. Make a backup of the relevant keyboard file for your locale. In my case, this is Keyboard-en.plist or Keyboard-en_GB.plist.
> 3. Add custom characters or change the characters that you wish, then save the file.
> 4. Log out and back in for the changes to take effect in all apps.

For example, you can add the following:

```
<!-- language: xml -->

    <key>Roman-Accent-0</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>{ [</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>{ [</string>
    </dict>
```

Files in /System are protected by System Integrity Protection. If you wish to edit the file, you will need to disable this if you haven't done so already.

> To disable System Integrity Protection, you can do the following:
>
> 1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
> 2. Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
> 3. Run the following command in Terminal:
>
>    ```
>    csrutil disable
>    ```
> 4. Restart.

[Disable OS X El Capitan Rootless and permit write actions to System Integrity Protection locations](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/)

You can re-enable it once you've edited the file.